# Malformed XML fragment: a name was started with an invalid character 'ñ'

Tags: xml, web-services, progress-4gl

Sorry for my bad english.
I'm a Progress 4GL developer.
I get the following error **Malformed XML fragment: a name was started with an invalid character 'ñ'** when I execute the RUN statement to execute a method of a web service

The XML structure is this:

```
<RecuperarDatosGeneralesVehiculoXCodigoInfoAuto 
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.com.ar/">
    <ns0:lsCodInfoAuto>12410</ns0:lsCodInfoAuto>
    <ns0:añoModelo>2012</ns0:añoModelo>
</RecuperarDatosGeneralesVehiculoXCodigoInfoAuto>
```

This structure can not be modified because it is designed by the developers of the Web Services.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you have any processing instruction on your XML return value? Anything like `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>` ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873228/is-it-appropriate-to-use-non-ascii-natural-language-xml-tags . It appears to be _legal_ to do that, so the first thing to check is whether the ñ character was written in the correct encoding to be used with this application. There is debate whether it is a good idea to use non-ASCII letters.

Comment: Rubens, yes I have but still got the error

Comment: Yep, you need to be sure the encoding is correctly specified.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to clarify that the programming language is already Progress 4GL and tried to pass the corresponding encoding. But I still get the same error.

Comment: 1) is the letter really correct? Even if OK by standards it is strange. 2) how do you create the xml if done in 4GL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think this is about the codepage/character set of the file. I tried to copy-paste your xml into a document, adding the xml-start tag and read it in a Progress session and got an error similar to yours. Also opening the same file in different browsers produced errors.

However, the example below produces xml with a ñ in a tag and is possible to open not only in Progress (the example does exactly that), but also in different browsers.

I also read the xml into a general xml document in Progress and save a copy of it - still with the ñ character in the tag.

While the xml isn't 100% formed like yours it's still an example that might help you on the way.

```
/* 
Defining a temp-table named ttRecuperarDatos.
Note: 
1) I have to put the long name (RecuperarDatosGeneralesVehiculoXCodigoInfoAuto) 
as SERIALIZE-NAME (could use XML-NODE-NAME as well) since Progress only allows for 
32 character long names 

2) añoModelo needs to be put AS SERIALIZE-NAME as well since
Progress wont let me use special character as field names. 

*/

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttRecuperarDatos NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "RecuperarDatosGeneralesVehiculoXCodigoInfoAuto"
    FIELD lsCodInfoAuto AS CHARACTER 
    FIELD anoModelo     AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "añoModelo".

/* Defining a copy of the first temp-table */
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttCopy SERIALIZE-NAME "RecuperarDatosGeneralesVehiculoXCodigoInfoAuto" LIKE ttRecuperarDatos .

/* Define a handle to a general xml-document */
DEFINE VARIABLE hXml AS HANDLE      NO-UNDO.


/* Create two records */
CREATE ttRecuperarDatos.
ASSIGN 
    ttRecuperarDatos.lsCodInfoAuto = "abc123"
    ttRecuperarDatos.anoModelo     = "1998".

CREATE ttRecuperarDatos.
ASSIGN 
    ttRecuperarDatos.lsCodInfoAuto = "cde444"
    ttRecuperarDatos.anoModelo     = "2004".

/* Write content to file */
TEMP-TABLE ttRecuperarDatos:WRITE-XML("FILE","c:\temp\testfile.xml").

/* Read content from file into second temp-table */
TEMP-TABLE ttCopy:READ-XML( "FILE"
                          , "c:\temp\testfile.xml"
                          , "EMPTY"
                          , ""
                          , FALSE).

/* Display records just to prove the READ-XML worked */
FOR EACH ttCopy:
    DISPLAY ttCopy.
END.


/* Create a new xml document */
CREATE X-DOCUMENT hXml.

/* Load content into it */
hXml:LOAD("FILE","c:\temp\testfile.xml", FALSE).

/* Save a copy to disc */
hXml:SAVE("FILE","c:\temp\testfile_copy.xml").

/* Cleanup */
DELETE OBJECT hXml.
```